# Django Not Displaying Text from HttpResponse in Firefox, works in IE/iOS Browsers

Tags: django, firefox, httpresponse

Hi I have a prototype website that i am working on in django... it creates a string message and is returned in an HttpResponse.

This code does render a page correctly in internet explorer and iOS, but does not in Firefox. Can you tell me what i need to do differently to make this work on all browsers (send a text response back). At some point, i will likely either return JSON back, or return a variable to be displayed in a template, but not sure why the initial text does not work correctly in Firefox. Thank you!

```
        try:
            data="create some message... (code working here)"

        except:
            data="Could not create the message"

        ###Generate the response to send back
        response=HttpResponse(str(data))
        return response
```

Comment: When catching exceptions, mention specific exceptions whenever possible instead of using a bare except: clause.

Comment: str(data) is redundant. data is always a string.

Comment: `response=HttpResponse(str(data)); return response` can be less complex by returning the response in one statement: `return HttpResonse(data)`

Comment: Did you use the FF developer tools to inspect the source and console output?

Comment: thanks! will add.... any idea while firefox wont just render the text while two other browsers will?

Comment: will gert FFDev going... this is a new virtual machine without all the widgets installed yet.. get back shortly! Thanks for the assist